# jquery - issue populating hidden div

Tags: jquery, css, ajax

I have a div that I am populating with an ajax call to flickr. The goal is to fill the div with photos and then fadeIn the div. The problem is that I am using javascript to distribute the photos into 3 columns based on whichever column is shortest, but if the div is initially hidden there are no dimensions so the distribution script fails and puts all images in the first column.

Is there a way to hide the div but let it still have height? Using `visibility: hidden` doesn't work by the way.

Comment: Do all the pictures have the same size or different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a hack, you can often fake invisibility by setting an element's margin to -3000px (or any other large number). The element will retain its width and height but be rendered outside of the screen's view.

Comment: This doesn't cause scroll bars?

Comment: This does indeed work. I just had to figure out the sequence. `margin: -9999px`, `load content`, `margin: ''`, `hide`, `fadeIn`. It is causing one minor annoying issue with the wrapping div but that is another matter.

Comment: This shouldn't normally cause scroll-bars but it might depend on your existing css and html. For example, try this test html: <html><body> <input type="text" style="margin-left: -3000px" /></body></html>

Answer (score 0):

It's for stuff like this that I like to use [jQuery Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/). Make sure to check out the [basic single-column demo](http://masonry.desandro.com/demos/basic-single-column.html). I'm thinking that it's this effect that you want to achieve.

Comment: Yeah I saw Masonry after I made my own script. It looks cool but I don't really need it at this point.